# "Comment too short" doesn't show up on mobile

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

On the mobile site, when I submit a <15 character comment nothing happens.

No notification, comment not added, comment text stays the same. It confused me at first; I refreshed the page twice before I figured it out.

Comment: I can confirm this happens.

Comment: @Prof Hmm... So it's confirmed by a doorknob and a pickle. There's some strange names here on SO `:P`

Comment: That's Prof Pickle to you. :P